# I can't access the web page DOM from a Chrome Extension pop up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am struggling to access the DOM of the web page for my Chrome Extension.

In one extension I made, my extension parses the DOM from the `content.js` file without issue. This happens as the page loads. The user does not need to interact/open the extension at all, it just needs to be running in the backgorund.

Now I'm trying to trigger this from a button. This means the user will click the extension icon in the browser, and the `popup.html` will show some HTML (including the button).

This is where the problem lies for me. When I now try access the DOM (via click event of the button), it shows the popup.html's DOM, not the web page (The active tab).

So, a quick look through the docs (which I'm open to admit I struggle with) show that it could be a permissions issue. In my manifest.json file, I added

```
"permissions": [
"activeTab"
],
```

This didn't help :(

So in this new extension, I'm not using the background.js nor content.js .. I guess this is the problem, as the javascript I'm calling is embeded in the HTML pop up! This makes sense to me (as to the behaviour I'm getting).

How do I access the DOM of the active tab from the HTML pop up

Comment: The only way of accessing a page's DOM is by using a content script. Since you've set the `activeTab` permission you can use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to inject a content script into the active tab by omitting the first parameter (the `tabId`).

Comment: Crystal clear. Thank you @Titus. Do I delete or do you move to an answer

Comment: I will add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way of accessing a page's DOM is by using a content script. Since you've set the `activeTab` permission you can use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to inject a content script into the active tab by omitting the first parameter (the `tabId`).

Here is an example:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "content.js" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue, I click on the button to open an popup, then how do I access the contents of the popup.  Yes, you will need to use content scripts, but a trick I done to accomplish this, was when the popup is open, use window.name and get the name of that window.  Then you can reference that popup window by var test = window.name('', 'name of that window').  Then you can reference the dom elements of the popup from test.  Worked for me, let me know if I need to include some code to better explain.